# Flexbox item is not aligned when it line-breaks because of too much text

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is small codepen example of problem.
https://codepen.io/artyor/pen/OJMrXMX

```
<div class="wrap">
  <a>Row One</a>
  <a>Row Two</a>
  <a>Problematic Row</a>
  <a>Row Four</a>
  <a>Row Five</a>
</div>

<style>
body{ 
  margin: 0; 
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap{
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background: silver;
  font-size: 30px;

  
  /* problem*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap > a{
    border: 1px solid red;
}   
</style>
```

Once the text in  tag is too long, it line-breaks, which is normal and what I want.
But when that happens it puts only that item out of the flow, it's not centered anymore, and even if I somehow make it centered, it still takes full width of container(.wrap).

How do I make it act like other  tags?

Answer (score 0):

Does this provide an answer for you?

```css
body{ 
  margin: 0; 
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap{
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  background: silver;
  font-size: 30px;

  
  /* problem*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap > a{
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a>Row One</a>
  <a>Row Two</a>
  <a>Problematic Row</a>
  <a>Row Four</a>
  <a>Row Five</a>
</div>
```

I just inserted these properties in `.wrap` class:

- `max-width: 150px` to set the maximum value achievable for the elements width;
- `text-align: center` to make the text aligned at the center horizontally.

Also I changed the values of `.wrap > a` `width` to `150px`, to make the example the most clear possible.

Comment: Thanks, but I cant use break-all, and with break-word it doesn't work.

Comment: `word-wrap: break all` has been removed

Comment: It still has the same problem like my sample, the problematic row <a> tag will take full width, thus it will be clickable on full width, unlike other tags that will be only clickable on text space. To check it, add 400px to wrapper, and remove width on a tags.

Comment: So... are you looking for a scrollbar or other stuff? I'm not sure to have understood what you exactly mean